# How to catch this nth-child() with css

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

```
<ul>
<div id="consolidation-checkboxes-container" class="consolidation-checkboxes container" style="height: 104px;">                     
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
    <li>one</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
    <li>two</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link bordered" target="_blank">
    <li>three</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
    <li>four</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
    <li>five</li></a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
    <li>six</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
        <li>seven</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
        <li>eight</li>
    </a>

</div>
</ul>
```

I would like  the seventh *li* not have bullet.Is this possible to be done with css, because I am not allowed to change the html

Comment: Your HTML is invalid...`ul` can only contain `li`...you need to put the `a` inside the `li` and remove the `div`.

Comment: follow the rule of `HTML`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can also do like this to exactly catch the nth-child..

```
ul > div > a:nth-child(7) > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If your html is the one you provide you can use the following code:

```css
ul div a:nth-child(7) li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div id="consolidation-checkboxes-container" class="consolidation-checkboxes container" style="height: 104px;">
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
      <li>one</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
      <li>two</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link bordered" target="_blank">
      <li>three</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
      <li>four</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
      <li>five</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
      <li>six</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
      <li>seven</li>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">
      <li>eight</li>
    </a>

  </div>
</ul>
```

Additional as mention in comments `ul` element can only contain zero or more `li` elements, eventually mixed with `ol` and `ul` elements. So you can change your html mark up to be valid like:

```css
ul li:nth-child(7) {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">one</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">two</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="consolidation-link bordered" target="_blank">three</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">four</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">five</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">six</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">seven</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="consolidation-link" target="_blank">eight</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A general question, isn't it common to set first the `<li>` and than the `<a>`? like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cL0a8uL6/)

Comment: @MarioKurzweil Add an alternative.

Comment: @Mario Kurzweil: It is. However the first example is reproduced from the original markup above, which is rife with errors.